# Match a filename in directory folder to get its extension by php

Tags: php

I want to copy my file(audio/video) name from my directory folder and paste it to my form `name` field. So here is no extension. When I click submit, I want to match this file if exist in directory folder and if exist, get its extension. Add this extension with the file name to save it to `download` field in sql.

Here I found this way to do it but I worried about more and more different extension.
Have any others way to do it?

```
$name = 'File name';
$exts =  array('mkv','avi','3gp','mp4','kmv','flv','rar','FLV','rmvb','dat','divx','mpg','wav','amr','mp3','wma');
foreach ($exts as $ext) {
    if (file_exists("../folder/" . $name . "." . $ext)) {
        $path = "" . $name . "." . $ext;
        echo $path;

        $downloadFile = $path;
    }
}
```

Comment: In general using a string separation (anker it on the _last_ dot in the file name) is more efficient, since you do not have to loop. So you `glob()` the folder contents, take the file name and separate it. However a general remark: why are those old fashioned "file name extensions" that important to you?

Comment: #arkascha thank you for glob() idea.